# hybridshapefill function of CATIA

Tags: vba, catia

I am currently working on an CATIA V5 macro, that uses the generative shape design function named "hybridshapefill". Sometimes it says the set of normals is too scattered to construct the hybridshapefill.
Does someone know how the hybridshapefill can be constructed anyways, or why this error occurs?

What does the hybrid shape fill exactly construct? Is it something like a minimal surface? Does CATIA provide any insight in its functions?

Comment: [Click here.](http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/interfaces/interface_HybridShapeFill.htm) `HybridShapeFill` produces `Fill` object. The curves/lines should be selected in the order so that they make a closed contour. Maybe this is your issue?

Comment: I already made sure that the contour is closed

Comment: are the curves/lines selected in proper order (the ends of two consecutive lines (selected one by one) coincide)? What happens if you create Fill object manually (without a code)?

Comment: yes, they are. By hand I get the same error message, in German it says "Normalenset zu verstreut" I do not know the term of the english error message

Comment: Share a screenshot of the geometry somehow. It's difficult to judge from words.